# Reading data from .csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, graph, charts

Title is self explanatory. I have no experience in JavaScript but I need to use it for this project...I am utilizing eCharts to display the data in a graph.

CSV Data (About 2000 more lines like this):

```
Collection Name,Rank,Volume,Change in the last 24h,Change in the last 7 days,Floor 
Price,Owners,Amount of items
The Degenaissance,50,77.96,+414.26%,+202.70%,1.44,2.3K,2.5K
```

I can also take out the name of the categories if necessary (like I said, I have no idea how this works).

JS-Code that I could come up with until now (pretty much just copy-pasted from echarts):

```
option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked Line'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Email', 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [600, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
      name: 'Video Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    }
  ]
};
```

The data from the .csv should end up in series[]. Is there like a function that I can use to directly pull the data from line... and input it to the variable... ect.? Or what would be a good approach to this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example JavaScript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: Everything I found on the topic of jquery included using <script> in HTML but I'm not using HTML. Do you know what a replacement for that would be in a normal JS file?